# Mounting files into quarkus Dev Services for Database

Tags: postgresql, quarkus

I'm using quarkus and the DevServices to start a postgresql database.
I want to initilize this database with a csv file. To do so I want to mount a csv file into the container of postgresql which is started with DevServices, so that I can initalize my database with "COPY ... FROM" in the init script.

I follow [the quarkus documentation for database dev services](https://quarkus.io/guides/databases-dev-services#mapping-volumes-into-dev-services-for-database):

I've tried to add the following to  [my project](https://github.com/nichell/q-project-postgresql) in the application properties:

```
quarkus.datasource.devservices.volumes."/resources/init/"=/container/resources/
```

or

```
quarkus.datasource.devservices.volumes."src/main/resources/init/"=/container/resources/
```

The problem is that my csv file isn't mounted correctly: The path /container/resources is in the postgres container but the resources folder is empty. It should contain the csv-file titanic.csv.

What path do I need to provide?

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide an absolute path where your resource is located. However, since you want to bind a resource that is in your classpath already, you can use:

```
quarkus.datasource.devservices.volumes."classpath:./init"=/container/resources
```

Where "." stands for the path at either "src/test/resources" if exists or "src/main/resources".

I hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've tried the above and get ````Task :quarkusAppPartsBuild FAILED```` when I use "gradlew clean build". Without the line the build works.

Answer (score 0):

The [example in the documentation](https://quarkus.io/guides/databases-dev-services#mapping-volumes-into-dev-services-for-database) explains it well, I think:

```
# Using a filesystem volume:
quarkus.datasource.devservices.volumes."/path/from"=/container/to 
# Using a classpath volume:
quarkus.datasource.devservices.volumes."classpath:./file"=/container/to
```

Your attempts are wrong for several reasons:

1. Your file is in your application resources and thus will be available in the classpath, so you probably should use the `classpath:` variant instead of the filesystem variant you're using.
2. Your first attempt uses `"/resources/init/"`, which is an absolute path and probably doesn't match anything (unless you have a `resources` directory at the root of your filesystem and an `init` directory inside it, but I doubt that).
3. Your second attempt uses `src/main/resources/init/` assuming paths are relative to your project's root directory, but I doubt they are. More likely they're relative to whatever directory you start your application from (and in the case of tests with Maven, that's probably `./target`).

In your case I'd try this instead?

```
quarkus.datasource.devservices.volumes."classpath:./init/"=/container/resources/
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've tried the above and also with absolute path:
````quarkus.datasource.devservices.volumes."C:/Users/n.nichell/IdeaProjects/q-project-postgresql/src/main/resources/init"=/container/resources/"```` or ````quarkus.datasource.devservices.volumes."C:\\Users\\n.nichell\\IdeaProjects\\q-project-postgresql\\src\\main\\resources\\init\\"=/container/resources/" ````but in both cases the build does not work.

Comment: Ah, windows. Maybe `quarkus.datasource.devservices.volumes."C:\Users\n.nichell\IdeaProjects\q-project-postgresql\src\main\resources\init\"=/container/resources/" ? See https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/#read-only